# Django Admin Intermittently Returning 404 On Model Edit

Tags: python, django, django-admin, http-status-code-404

We're using the Django Admin to maintain some data that's exported to a few of our sites. Sometimes when clicking through the standard changelist view to get a model edit form instead of being routed to the correct page we're getting the Django 404 page/template.

It was happening somewhat sporatically, and we could for a while reproduce it by reloading three times:

- First F5: 404
- Second F5: 404
- Third F5: Object change form loads correctly

But lately it's been returning 404 more often than not. It seems to reduce the odds of returning 404 when we bounce apache (gracefully) and gets worse (again, seemingly) with more requests.

Running Django 1.2.1 on Fast-CGI/MySQL 5.1.x

FWIW, I can't reproduce the problem on my VM, but I'm running mod_wsgi there and have Debug=True set in the settings. Otherwise the code and database is identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem.  The solution for me was to move my calls to `admin.site.register()` to `admin.py`.  With DEBUG set to false, your models are lazily loaded, so the registration calls don't always get made.  Apparently `admin.py` is always loaded at init time, however.

Comment: Where else would your admin.site.register() calls be? Mine already in admin.py of each app but getting this issue now only in prod with apache and not manage.py runserver

Comment: hi @radtek, are you able to solve this, i am getting same issue only on prod.

Comment: Yup I solved it by moving my `admin.site.register()` to `admin.py` nowhere else

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey did you find another cause? My `register()` calls are in `admin.py` but still getting the issue - consistently the first call to a change admin screen during unit tests. Second and subsequent all work fine. Also tried @decorating admin classes, etc.) Oddly the earlier call needn't be to an admin screen - calling a DRF view also fixes a subsequent change screen visit.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem until last week. after i track this error for couple of months and i found 404 raising at django source code.

i modified the file /path/to/django/contrib/admin/options.py get_object() method of ModuleAdmin class.
Note: i use Django 1.3.1

somehow django cannot find object with pk object_id in queryset. so i modified it like this:

```
def get_object(self, request, object_id):
    ....
    queryset = self.queryset(request)
    model = queryset.model
    obj = None

    #first search the object with original way
    try:
        object_id = model._meta.pk.to_python(object_id)
        obj = queryset.get(pk=object_id)
    except:
        #print "DEBUG: > first try does not exist (%s)" % str(object_id)
        obj = None

    if obj is None: 
        #if object doesn't exist in queryset, search in db
        try:
            object_id = model._meta.pk.to_python(object_id)
            obj = model.objects.get(pk=object_id)
            #print "DEBUG: > second try found %s" % str(obj)
        except (model.DoesNotExist, ValidationError):
            #print "DEBUG: > second try does not exist"
            obj = None
    return obj
```

i know it's not a good thing to change something in django's source, so use at your own risk !

Answer (score 0):

See if the alternate WSGI script at the end of:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

makes a difference.

Comment: Tried the alternative wsgi.py script, didn't work for me. The 404 page that I am getting is also broken, all static images not displaying, translations broken. The 404 page on other urls works fine. (django 1.6.8 and mod_wsgi apache)

Comment: That blog post is very out of date now and shouldn't be used. Django has changed a lot since then.

Comment: apache mod_wsgi behaves differently from say gunicorn + wsgi, so I encountered this 404 issue only when running on mod_wsgi. The problem turned out to be an objects variable conditionally declared outside of init. mod_wsgi running in the Beanstalk didn't like it, but worked fine everywhere else. Does that even make sense?  Very specific issue though in my case.

Comment: No, your description doesn't make sense so no idea what you are talking about. If you want to pursue it further, use the mod_wsgi mailing list to ask about it and why gunicorn behaves differently.

Comment: I already fixed the issue as per above. Just not sure why mod_wsgi and gunicorn /wsgi would give me different results. I wont be pursuing it further no.