# Django - empty Admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I have just started deploying my first large django project. I have setup the admin but when I login - everything is empty! I haven't seen this before, so I'm at a loss as to where to look for the issue. Below is a screenshot:

[image: django admin screeshot]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Django?

Comment: This is on hosted server - so I would be surprised if the problem is with the Django installation.

Comment: Then upload the poll tutorial project and try to reproduce it. If you can reproduce it, file a help ticket with your host.

Comment: I had similar issues, found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158589/django-admin-intermittently-returning-404-on-model-edit)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wild hunch but try using 
    **admin.autodiscover()**
in your url file. For more info refer to the [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) tutorial.

Comment: Nope. admin.autodiscover() is enabled. The admin works fine with my project in development using runserver.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if it is a newbie mistake you make during deployment on production server, but perhaps you could check this:

see the following unicode issue:

> https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#Blankobjectnames

Comment: All my models have unicode methods - as I say above all is fine in development.